# Group Elements with a DIV

Tags: php, html, wordpress, grouping

My DOM structure looks like

```
<h2>Month</h2>
<article class="test">test</article>
<article class="test">test</article>
<article class="test">test</article>
<article class="test">test</article>
<article class="test">test</article>
<h2>next Month</h2>
<article class="test">test</article>
<article class="test">test</article>
```

But I want around the  a DIV Element:

```
<div class="month">
<h2>Month</h2>
<article class="test">test</article">
<article class="test">test</article">
<article class="test">test</article">
</div>
```

In my PHP Function I have these lines:

```
$ts_monat = strftime("%m",$timestamp);  
if($ts_monat != $monat_l) 
{
    echo '<h3 class="spacer_monat" id="'. $monat[$ts_monat] .'">'. $monat[$ts_monat] .'</h3>';
} 
$monat_l = $ts_monat;
```

after this I output my articles ...

but I don't know how I can wrap a div around them ...

Comment: Probably you need to use a DOM Parser in php for this

Comment: How is one line of code making all that HTML?  Where is your loop?

Comment: this is a wordpress loop ...

Comment: I'm not following. You have `<h3` in your PHP but `<h2>` in your HTML. It can't be the code responsible for the HTML's generation.

Comment: this code does not generate html you provided.

Comment: sorry bad example ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$str = '<div class="month">';

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 

$loop->the_post();
$i++;

?>

<?php
$timestamp = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_tatort_datum_timestamp', true );


$ts_jahr = strftime("%Y",$timestamp);   
if($ts_jahr != $jahr_l) 
{
    $str .= '<h2 class="spacer_jahr" id="'. $ts_jahr .'">'. $ts_jahr .'</h2>';
} 
$jahr_l = $ts_jahr; 


$ts_monat = strftime("%m",$timestamp);      
if($ts_monat != $monat_l) 
{
    $str .= '<h3 class="spacer_monat" id="'. strtolower($monat[$ts_monat]) . "_" . $ts_jahr. '">'. $monat[$ts_monat] .'</h3>';
} 
$monat_l = $ts_monat;

<article>
</article>
endwhile; 
$str .= '</div>';
echo $str;
```

Comment: what you are getting. tell me so that i can helpful you much more.

Comment: this wraps only a div around the headline ... but i need it around the headline + article ... <div><h3><article><article></div>

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array( 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_type' => 'tatort', 'posts_per_page' => $count_posts,
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => '_tatort_datum_timestamp', 'order' => 'DESC'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );   

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$i++;

?>

<?php
$timestamp = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_tatort_datum_timestamp', true );


$ts_jahr = strftime("%Y",$timestamp);   
if($ts_jahr != $jahr_l) 
{
    echo '<h2 class="spacer_jahr" id="'. $ts_jahr .'">'. $ts_jahr .'</h2>';
} 
$jahr_l = $ts_jahr; 


$ts_monat = strftime("%m",$timestamp);      
if($ts_monat != $monat_l) 
{
    echo '<h3 class="spacer_monat" id="'. strtolower($monat[$ts_monat]) . "_" . $ts_jahr. '">'. $monat[$ts_monat] .'</h3>';
} 
$monat_l = $ts_monat;

<article>
</article>
endwhile; wp_reset_query();
```

This is the Full Version of the Wordpress Loop

Answer (score 0):

alright ... now the output is

```
<div class="month">
<h2>Headline</h2>
<h3>Headline</h3>
<article>Content</article>
</div>
<article>Content</article>
<article>Content</article>
<h3>Headline</h3>
```